# Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate when performing binomial glmer in R

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to perform a glmer in R using a binomial response.  Here is the code:

```
    hg1<-glmer(Used~ size*daytime + (1|Bird), family=binomial(link=logit), data=hg.model).
```

Used is a 1 or 0, size is area in Hectares, daytime is distance in meters, and Bird is my random effects variable.  When I run it, I get the following,

```
    Error: (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
    In addition: Warning message:
    Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

The model doesn't run.  When I run the model using additive terms:

```
    hg1<-glmer(Used~ size + daytime + (1|Bird), family=binomial(link=logit), data=hg.model)
```

I get the following messages, but the model does run:

```
    Warning messages:
    1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling 
    2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
      Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.555943 (tol = 0.001, component 2)
    3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
      Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
     - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue   ratio
     - Rescale variables?
```

Any reason why the model won't run when I cross variables (in any combination) and how do I fix it?  Thanks

Comment: It can be dependent on how much data you have. How many observations are there? Also, try [scaling/centering](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel/12080) your predictors.

Comment: I scaled my data based on your suggestion (and example) and now the analysis works.  Thank you!

Comment: this is probably a complete separation problem.